# Matrix multiplication Q.W not working - Result=matrix Q . matrix W

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, dot

When I write the code to do the dot product between two matrices, Mathematica does not compute it:

[image]

How can I get the right matrix?

---

EDIT

[image]

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: You should include "," in your the matrixdefinition: `Q={{a,b},{c,d}}`

Comment: Hello @UlrichNeumann, I get the same error.

Comment: remove `MatrixForm` from rhs of the definitions.

Comment: Thank you very much @kglr.